# Playwright - generate a separate .html report for each test

Tags: playwright

I've written a script to loop through a series of test cases and run the same test for each case. The test cases are defined as a JSON array in a separate file. I'd like to product a separate HTML report for each iteration. Is this possible? Here's the bare bones of my code...

```
import { cases } from 'cases.json';

cases.forEach( case => {

    test(case.casenmbr, async ({ page }) => {
      // test here
    });

});
```

Ideally the HTML report would be named for the casenmbr variable.

I've experimented with the configuration file and tried copying the report.html file to another filename at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution I've found is to write a custom reporter class...

```
import {
  FullConfig, FullResult, Reporter, Suite, TestCase, TestResult
} from "@playwright/test/reporter";

const fs = require("fs");

class CustomReport {

  onBegin(config, suite) {
  }
  
  onTestBegin(test, result) {
  }
  
  onTestEnd(test, result) {
    var html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
    html += `<html>\n<head>\n<title>${test.title}</title>\n</head>\n<body>`;
    html += `<h1>test: ${test.title} status: ${result.status}</h1>\n`;
    html += "<table>"
    for ( const steppe of result.steps ){ // not a typo, step is reserved
      html += `<tr><td>${steppe.title}</td><td>${steppe.startTime}</td><td>${steppe.duration}</td></tr>\n`;
    }
    html += "</table></body></html>";
    fs.writeFile(`${test.title}.html`, html, err => {if (err){console.log(err)}});
  }
  
  onEnd(result) {
  }

}
  
export default CustomReport;
```

...and add this to playwright.config.js...

```
reporter: [['html'],['./custom-report.js']],
```